# How to pause stream consumption in caolan/async queue v3

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, queue, async.js

I have a working stream consumer in caolan v2.6.3 which basically pauses the stream consumption as soon as the queue is saturated and resumes after it's drained:

```js
let q = async.queue(function(tasks, callback) {
  // ...
  callback()
}, 4);

q.drain = function() {
  some_readable_stream.resume()
}

q.saturated = function() {
  some_readable_stream.pause();
}

some_readable_stream.on("data", function(data) {
  q.push(data);
});
```

It seems there's breaking change in v3 After updating, above logic fails with error

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'saturated' of object '#<Object>'
```

But I am uncertain what would be the correct replacement for this in v3.

Anyone any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

properties from v2 `q.saturated`, `q.unsaturated` and `q.drain` are methods in v3, so it can be solved like this:

```
// ...

q.drain(function() {
  some_readable_stream.resume()
})

q.saturated(function() {
  some_readable_stream.pause();
})

//...
```